# Definition of a proxy in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

An ARIMA model is a statistical model. I'm having problems to understand it.

[image]

The definition I found on [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/proxy):

> A situation, process, or activity to which another situation, etc. is
> compared, especially in order to calculate how successful or
> unsuccessful it is

The examples I found on internet don't seem help much in this context. Could you help me with other examples in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the ARIMA model isn't exactly equivalent to N, it can be a proxy for it in the sense of a stand-in, since the aim is to "get better information from our preliminary LFT model." The ARIMA model represents/does the job of/approximates N.

In other words, using the ARIMA model gives a more accurate evaluation than estimating as was done in (5.3.1).

**proxy** (n.)

> **3.a** A person appointed or authorized to act on behalf of another; an
> attorney; a representative, an agent; **a substitute**.
>
> **b.** figurative.
> *Leaving only lights of cities and fires to serve as ghostly proxies of the sites of human activity.*
>
> **4.** *Chiefly Science and Economics*. A variable that can be used as an
> **indirect estimate** of another variable with which it is correlated;
> (more generally) a property used as an estimate or indicator of
> another with which it is associated. **Frequently attributive**. OED

In this case ARIMA is *proxy model* for N.

---

> Another common example of latent variables is when the quantity we can
> measure is a **proxy** for the variable we are interested in, such as
> the earlier example where we used TDR as a proxy for soil moisture
> (section 6.3). [M. C. Dietze; *Ecological Forecasting*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ecological_Forecasting/EGqYDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22proxy%20for%20the%20variable%22&pg=PA109&printsec=frontcover), p.109

> The number of living children, which is a **proxy** for the variable
> representing household structure, is expected to capture the effect of
> informal familial support for their aged parent upon his/her
> participation. [N. Ogawa et al.; *Human Resources in
> Development Along the Asia-Pacific Rim*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Human_Resources_in_Development_Along_the/9bizAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22proxy%20for%20the%20variable%22&dq=%22proxy%20for%20the%20variable%22&printsec=frontcover), p.361

> A **proxy variable** is a variable that is used to measure an unobservable
> quantity of interest. Although a proxy variable is not a direct
> measure of the desired quantity, a good proxy variable is strongly
> related to the unobserved variable of interest. [M. Lewis-Beck et al.;
> *The SAGE Encyclopedia of Social Science Research Methods*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_SAGE_Encyclopedia_of_Social_Science/iu1yAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22proxy%20variable%22&pg=PA878&printsec=frontcover), p.878